# Adding RTC Library for Arduino Project in Visual Studio

Tags: arduino-mega, library, rtc, visualstudio

I am working in an Arduino project in visual studio. I need to get and set time to a RTC clock. That's why I am adding a ds3231 header file in my project from [GitHub](https://github.com/rodan/ds3231). When I want to build "it's showing me linking error.

```
cccSeqVu.ltrans0.o*: (.text.startup+0x1ea): undefined reference to DS3231_init(unsigned char)
```

My code is given below.

```
   #include <Wire.h>
   #include "ds3231.h"
  

    void setup(){
        Wire.begin();
        DS3231_init(0x4);
    }
    
    void loop(){
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to find out what I have missed.

Comment: add the whole library, not just the header file

Comment: How to add the whole library in visual studio?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use platformio